# C# Windows Forms Print Dialog box click OK twice to respond

Tags: c#, printing, printdialog

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, .net Framework 3.5 for a Windows forms client-server app that I'm working on. There is a weird bug when I run the program and try to print. The print dialog box opens, but I have to click the OK button twice for it to work. After the second click it works fine, no errors. When I put a breakpoint on: if (result == DialogResult.OK) , the breakpoint doesn't trigger until the second click. Here is the  code:

```
private void tbPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        printDialog1.Document = pDoc;

        DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
            pDoc.Print();
        }
        ...
```

This is driving me crazy, and I can't see anything else that would interfere with it.

Comment: Can you show us the code in the printDialog when it should send the result as DialogResult.OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is an issue similar to this one: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/681a50b4-4ae3-407a-a747-87fb3eb427fd

Comment: This seems to be it. When I use a regular button instead of a toolstrip button it works with one click!

Comment: Here is the fix for the problem with the toolstrip and printdialog: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1746116.

Comment: It fixes the problem in theory, but you cannot get back the DialogResult from the printdialog, so it's not really a practical fix.

Comment: You can wrap whatever needs the result into a method called by the delegate. Just had the same problem, in my case it was easy: I have a ToolStripMenuItem for this functionality, so I just triggered ToolStripMenuItem_Clicked via delegate from ToolStripButton_Click :)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this while having the "first toolstrip click unrecognized" using an `OpenFileDialog` in C#/WinForms. After much cursing and googling, I did this:

1. In `toolstrip1_Click`:

   ```c#
   private void toolStrip1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     this.Validate();
   }
   ```
2. In the function that uses calls `OpenFileDialog`:

   ```c#
   private void locateMappingToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     OpenFileDialog dg = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
     if (dg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
       fileLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(dg.FileName);
       try
       {
         if (LoadData())
         {
           //Enable toolbar buttons
           toolStripButton3.Enabled = true;
           toolStripButton5.Enabled = true;
           toolStripButton1.Enabled = true;
           toolStripButton2.Enabled = true;
           searchParm.Enabled = true;
           toolStripButton4.Enabled = true;
           toolStripButton6.Enabled = true;
           exitToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
           EditorForm.ActiveForm.TopLevelControl.Focus();
         }
       }
       catch (Exception exx) 
       {
         MessageBox.Show(exx.Message + Environment.NewLine + exx.InnerException);
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Two things lines seem to be key:

- When the `OpenFileDialog` closes, focus needs to be reset to the main window (`EditorForm.ActiveForm.TopLevelControl.Focus();`)
- When the toolstrip button is clicked, the toolstrip validates itself (`this.Validate()`) and recognizes the mouse event.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it using a timer.

Drop a timer onto the form containing the toolstrip and turn it into a one shot timer with a delay of say 1mS. Note: Timer must initially have 'Enabled' set to 'False'

```
private void toolStripBtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   timer1.Interval = 1; // 1ms
   timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Create a timer tick event handler

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    PrintDialog printDialogue=new PrintDocument();        
    //Do your initialising here
    if(DialogResult.OK == printDialogue.ShowDialog())
    {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

It may be dirty but it got me out of a hole. HTH